# cannot resolve symbol 'view' in android studio

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-studio, android-imagebutton

i am trying to get a refernce to an image button in my fragment but coming accross with an error cannot resolve symbol view! i have imported View view but the erro is still there! can someone help clear this up! thank you

```
 public class ChildrensList extends Fragment {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrens_list,container,false);
            return rootView;

            ImageButton movedButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.movedButton);

            pigsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ChildrensList.this.getActivity(),downtown.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });


        }
```

Comment: low quality Question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your view is called `rootView` not `view`.

And also you're returning rootView. So there's no way, any of the further statements would be reachable.

Comment: i will accept this as the answer but its telling me to wait 6 minutes before i can accept! thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code at the top of the MainActivity.java file (preferably after the first line)

```
import android.view.View;
```